# How to do jprofiling in local machine without installing or downloading jprofiler in remote machine

Tags: jprofiler

I want to do jprofiling of our remote tomcat server from local machine.
In our linux box we dont have Jprofiler installed or downloaded. 
Please suggest if we can do remote profiling without installing Jprofiler in the remote machine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In JProfiler, invoke

Session->Integration Wizards->New Server Integration

choose the remote option and select the Tomcat server, then follow the steps in the integration wizard.